# Why my slider is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

My code is not working. It is not showing any slider on the page. I have followed the instructions given on this page http://unslider.com/. I am absolute beginner so please forgive me if I have done any silly mistake.

```css
.banner { position: relative; overflow: auto; }
    .banner li { list-style: none; }
        .banner ul li { float: left; }
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unslider.com/unslider.min.js"></script>

  <div id="gallery">
      <div class="banner">
         <ul>
             <li>This is a slide.</li>
             <li>This is another slide.</li>
            <li>This is a final slide.</li>
         </ul>
      </div>
  </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#gallery .banner').unslider();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Use a modern browser that isn't made by MicroSoft and hit F12 to open the console. Look at the "console" tab and see if there are any errors.

Comment: can you provide the live url, Then it would be easy for us to help.

Comment: Thanks a lot @adeneo. i didnt knew about that console and now I have solved the problem!

Comment: That's like the wrench of webdevelopment, always keep the console open.

Answer (score 0):

Complete slider source URL

Go through the above url u can download the Zip file then verify the style sheet and image folder as well